# When I set my div's css position to absolute the background-image disappears - help?

Tags: css, background-image, css-position

I'm trying to achieve the common design of a graphic at the top and bottom of my screen.  I have a div with a background-image at the top and another at the bottom.  No problems with the top one but of course I want the 'bottom' one to stay at the bottom of my page.  To do this I set a containing div with position:relative and then set the 'bottom' div {position:absolute; bottom:0;}
The problem is that as soon as I set the 'bottom' div position to absolute the background-image disappears!
I have a 40px height for the bottom div - but it is empty.

I have uploaded two version:  with the images showing but nasty positioning [www.NottsGuitar.co.uk](http://www.NottsGuitar.co.uk)  With absolute positioning : [www.NottsGuitar.co.uk/indexabsolute.php](http://www.nottsguitar.co.uk/indexAbsolute.php)

Answer (score 6):

Try setting `width: 100%;` also.

Comment: Yes, that makes the background reappear!  I set the top and bottom divs to 100% width and there they are - except now I have to fiddle with the positioning some more, 'cos I can now see that they're in the wrong place.  But that should be fine.  Thanks very much Ian.

Comment: Thank you 3+ years later for this, I had just been whipping together a div with background video, and I forgot width: 100%; on the parent div, and this made me doh and fixed it. Cheers :)